# How do I reattach a LocalDB database within VS2013 for further schema development?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, localdb

A couple of days ago I created (my first) localdb database from within Visual Studio 2013.  After defining the schema, I detached the db files from the server, within Visual Studio, so that I could move them to another project folder.  Now, for the life of me, I can not figure out how to re-attach the db so that I can update the schema.

I have been able to add the file to the Server Explorer in VS, and I can browse tables and the data.  However, from within the SQL Server Object Explorer window, I can not figure out how to get back my database.  How can I add it/re-attach it again so I can modify the db schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new query on that localdb instance and run the following (modify for your Database and FilePath specifics):

```
CREATE DATABASE DBname
  ON (FILENAME =
     'C:\Users\{Login}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\DBname\DBname.mdf'), 
     (FILENAME =
     'C:\Users\{Login}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\DBname\DBname.ldf') 
  FOR ATTACH;
```

It worked as expected for me. I detached a database and reattached it via the above command.

PLEASE NOTE: The O.P. reported back:

> I had to disconnect from the Server Explorer window. Otherwise, I was getting a "File Already In Use" error message.

Comment: Bingo! That did it.  It is also worth mentioning that I had to disconnect from the Server Explorer window.  Otherwise, I was getting a "File Already In Use" error message.